# Why this is giving me out of range(lst3.append(lst4 [ j ] ) )?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def mergeList(lst1,lst2):
lst3=[]
lst4=[]
if len(lst1)>len(lst2):
    for i in range(len(lst2)):

        lst3.append(lst1[i])
        lst3.append(lst2[i])
    lst4=lst1[len(lst2):len(lst1)] #here is python giving an error 
    for j in lst4:
        lst3.append(lst4[j])
else:
    for i in range(len(lst1)):

        lst3.append(lst1[i])
        lst3.append(lst2[i])
    lst4=lst2[len(lst1):len(lst2)]
    for j in lst4:
        lst3.append(lst4[j]) 
return lst3
```

This program merges 2 lists by interleaving their items, but if one list is greater than the other, the remaining items of the bigger list should be added to the merging list (lst3), item by item and not as a list.

I am getting index out of range at this line: lst3.append(lst4[j]).

I would really appreciate any suggestion that would help improve the code and solve the issue. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should have used a range while looping over lst4, or you should append J itself, for when you are doing j in lst4 you are getting the entry inside the list and not the first index in the list so either you should directly append it or use a range to get the first index in lst4, hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `list`s are zero-indexed. Since length, as determined by `len()`, is one-indexed, a `list` contains no element with an index equal to its length. Therefore, the slice of `lst1` that goes to `len(lst1)` will fail. If you want to go all the way to the end of `lst1`, simply omit the end of the slice, with `lst1[len(lst2):]`.

However, you can accomplish your task more easily with `zip()`, which will allow you to interleave the items, and then adding the remaining slice (if necessary) to the result:

```
def mergeList(lst1,lst2):
    lst3 = [item for t in zip(lst1, lst2) for item in t]
    if len(lst2) > len(lst1):
        lst3 += lst2[len(lst1):]
    if len(lst1) > len(lst2):
        lst3 += lst1[len(lst2):]
    return lst3
```

Comment: I would also note that later on OP's loop saying `for j in lst4; ... lst4[j]` would almost surely lead to an indexing error, and even if not, it would not be what they want to achieve.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Yeah, they'd need `append(j)` there. I figured it would be best to answer the immediate issue and then produce a clean solution rather than go through all the bugs.

Comment: I generally agree, but this is the kind of mistake that will probably bite OP in the butt again soon:)